# libusb_bulk_transfer() only works once

Tags: c++, libusb

I'm completely new to `Libusb`. I have written a c++ program in Ubuntu, I can connect to the device, I transfer some data to the device using `libusb_bulk_transfer(...)`. It works the first time, but the second time it returns -1 code. But when I reject the device and then when I reinstall the device to my computer, it works again.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libusb.h>

using namespace std;

#define BULK_OUTPUT LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_OUT | 0x01
#define BULK_INPUT LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_IN | 0x01

union usb_relator {
    unsigned char usb_data[4];
    int32_t number;
};

int main()
{
    libusb_device_handle *handle = NULL;

    if (libusb_init(NULL) < 0)
    {
        cout << "Failure" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    cout << "libusb inited successfully!!" << endl;

    libusb_device **devices;
    libusb_get_device_list(NULL, &devices);

    if (libusb_open(devices[0], &handle) < 0)
    {
        cout << "The device can not be open!!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    cout << "device opened successfully!!" << endl;

    libusb_device_descriptor descriptor;
    libusb_get_device_descriptor(devices[0], &descriptor);
    cout << "Vendor id: " << (int)descriptor.idVendor << endl;
    cout << "Product Id: " << (int)descriptor.idProduct << endl;

    libusb_detach_kernel_driver(handle, 0);
    if (libusb_claim_interface(handle, 0) < 0)
    {
        cout << "Can not claim interface!!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    cout << "Handle has been claimed!!" << endl;

    if (libusb_set_interface_alt_setting(handle, 0, 0) < 0)
    {
        cout << "Could not set alternate setting of the handle!!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    cout << "alt_setting set successfully!!" << endl;

    usb_relator number;

    cout << "Please insert your number: ";  
    cin >> number.number;

    int transfer_size;

    int returnCode = libusb_bulk_transfer(handle, BULK_OUTPUT, number.usb_data, sizeof(usb_relator), &transfer_size, 5000);
    if (returnCode == 0)
    {
        cout << "Data sent!!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Data could not be send!! Code: " << returnCode << endl;
    }

    returnCode = libusb_bulk_transfer(handle, BULK_INPUT, number.usb_data, sizeof(usb_relator), &transfer_size, 5000);
    if (returnCode == 0)
    {
        cout << "Data recieved!!" << endl;
        cout << number.usb_data << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Data could not recieve!! Code: " << returnCode << endl;
    }



    libusb_release_interface(handle, 0);
    libusb_close(handle);
    libusb_free_device_list(devices, 1);
    libusb_exit(NULL);
}
```

---

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, and I'm using VMWare. Thanks for your help.

---

I think it has something to do with the `libusb_detach_kernal_driver(...)` methode I call in my code.(Right before the line I claim the interface).